# How do I format a date field in Crystal Reports 2008?

Tags: date, date-format, crystal-reports-2008

I have two dates a "start" and "end" date I want to display them on the report like this:

"June 1 - 6, 2014"

Where "June 1" comes form the "start" date and "6, 2014" is from the "end" date.

The major issue is I can't get a (space) between month & day or a (, space) between day and year.

Comment: Please provide additional details that show exactly what you're trying to do.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like below:

```
CStr(Start,"MMM d")+" "+CStr(End,"d, yyyy");
```